# problema ao executar php

Tags: php, html

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema:

Eu criei um input e os valores que forem digitados nele, ao ser pressionado um botão devem ser mandados para um array no meu ".php".

O problema é que além de não estar capturando os valores, quando eu aperto o botão ele simplesmente me redireciona para o arquivo ".php" e mostra na tela todo o código que está dentro dele.

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Meu HTML:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Menu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stile.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="conteudo">
        <div id="adicionarItens">
                <h4>Dados</h4>
                <form action="sistema.php" method="post">
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="dados" value="" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" id="botaoE" value="submit me!" />
                    </p>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

e o PHP:

```php
    <?php  

        if(isset($_POST["dados"]))
        {
            $valor = $_POST["dados"];

            echo $valor;
        }
    ?>
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Isso deve acontecer porque você não está utilizando um servidor HTTP com suporte a linguagem PHP. Você precisará do Apache, Nginx ou semelhante para tal. Está utilizando algum destes?

Comment: Era realmente esse o problema, havia esquecido que para conseguir utilizar a linguagem php precisaria estar com o Apache ativo. Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Baixe um ambiente de desenvolvimento de PHP, por exemplo o XAMPP segue o link para download: https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/download.html